# ledmac issue with nested \edtext's

Tags: ledmac

Using the ledmac package the following command:

\edtext{John}{\Dfootnote{This is his given name.}}

gives the following output:

A footnote will appear at the bottom of the page (in the 4th of 4 levels of footnotes) which starts with the line number on which 'John' occurs, followed by 'John] This is his given name.'
Now I have two consecutive words in my text, lets say 'John' and 'Smith', where I want a Bfootnote attached to 'John Smith' and a Dfootnote attached to just 'John'.

So this is what I thought I should put in the input file:

\edtext{\edtext{John}{\Dfootnote{This is his given name.}} Smith}{\Bfootnote{This is his full name.}}

I want this to give the following output:

'John Smith' (on line 2, say)

'2 John Smith] This is his full name.' in the second level of footnotes

'2 John] This is his given name.' in the fourth level of footnotes

Indeed that used to work when I last used ledmac (10 years ago!)
But when I now run xelatex or pdflatex on the same input file that had these kind of instances 10 years ago, and that worked, I get the following error message:

! Undefined control sequence.
 \noexpand \vDfootnote {D}{{\l@d@nums 
                                                }{\@tag }{This is his given ...
l.22 ...Smith}{\Bfootnote{This is his full name.}}

Comment: ledmac is not maintened anymore. however, as it is a bug that I have introduce, I will try to correct this afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

Ledmac is not maintened anymore. However, as this bug was introduced by myself, and as it is easy to solve, I have published on CTAN a v. 0.19.4 to fix it.

Not that you should reledmac for new project / improvement of older project.

Comment: Many thanks indeed.  If this is an old input file, should I carry on using ledmac, or can I just use reledmac on the old input file?  And, sorry, what do you mean by: "published on CTAN a v. 0.19.4"? How do I get the benefit of that fix?

Comment: 1) for your first question, it's depend if you have overwritten some ledmac code. YOu can read migration handbook here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac

Comment: 2) for your second question: that mean I have send new version on CTAN. So you have to wait a little but and to update your latex distribution. Please read handbook of your latex distribution.

Comment: I don't know what I have done but the problem has completely gone away.  I have \usepackage{ledmac} in my input file, and I am now using my old ledmac.sty and the problem is no longer there.

Comment: yes, because you use a old ledmac, without this bug (but with other bug). So it is normal that is working.

Comment: There is one problem with using my old ledmac.sty.
Strangely I am almost certain it was not a problem when I was using this old ledmac.sty 10 years ago.
It is about hyphenation of a word within \edtext{}.
So "cetana\-dhisthita" if it is outside \edtext{} hyphenates fine.
But if I have \edtext{cetana\-dhisthita}{\Dfootnote{...}},
then when 
cetanadhisthita] shows up in the Dfootnote, it doesn't hyphenate (but stretches out into the right hand margin).

Comment: hum… I can't tell you. I have start modification of ledmac on v0.7.0. All other change are not from me. In any case, ledmac is not maintened anymore.

Comment: You should open a github issue with a mwe

Comment: Apologies that I'm a complete novice: what is a 'github issue with a mwe'?

Comment: please read https://github.com/maieul/ledmac#debug-and-feature-requests